# How exactly does Gibbs sampling work in Markov Networks?

Tags: gibbs, markov-random-field

I was going through the Probabilistic Graphical Modelling course by Stanford and they used a network such as this one-https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKh8B.jpg

Now if we want to sample P(A|B), how would we do that? My understanding is that we need to sample A, C and D while keeping the assigned value of B constant. However, the factors only provide us with Joint Probability table of P(A,B,C,D), so how would we compute 
P(C|B,D)? I am new to Markov Networks and Gibbs sampling so let me know where I might have gone wrong.

EDIT-How can we sample them if we don't know the individual probabilities or the conditional probabilities?

Thanks

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.